# Print the first number from line followed by tab and the line without the number

Tags: regex, sed

I am having a hard time doing this task with sed.

Sample Input:

```
X(996002) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
Y(300342) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
"(1200479) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "
```

Sample Output:

```
996002 TAB ) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
300342 TAB ) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
1200479 TAB ) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "
```

So far I have the following with sed:

```
sed -e 's/^.*\([0-9]*\)\(.*?\)$/\1 \t \2/gp' textfile.txt
```

but I think I don't understand something to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\)/\1\t /' file
996002   ) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
300342   ) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
1200479  ) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "
```

**Explanation:**

- `-i.bak` - Inline editing, save original file with `.bak` extension
- `^` - match linse start
- `^[^[:digit:]]\+` - match 1 or more non-digits at start
- `\(...\)` - Group enclosed content into a captured group #1
- `\([[:digit:]]\+\)` - Capture 1 or more digits in group #1
- `\1\t` - Replace by group #1 followed by a tab and a space

Comment: Yes sure, adding explanation in a bit.

Comment: I would capture 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?

```
 sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\)/\1\t/' file
```

with your input file:

```
kent$  cat f
X(996002) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
Y(300342) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
"(1200479) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "

kent$  sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\)/\1\t/' f
996002  ) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
300342  ) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
1200479 ) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F".[(]" '{sub(/)/,"\t)", $2);print $2}' file
996002  ) dsafsafdsfdsfds dsfdsfds dsfd ds
300342  ) dsfdsfhdsfhsa dsf;dsjfds f 15 16 .
1200479 ) dsfkjdsfhjfds dsfdsj sd "
```